# Unexpected behaviour of JavaFX GraphicsContext.translate

Tags: canvas, javafx-2

While exploring the capabilities of the JavaFX Canvas component I encountered a very strange behaviour when I used the `translate(double,double)` method:

When I stroke or fill a path after I have called the `translate` method, the path is drawn way out of place. In the example below it seems that the path is moved three times as much as I specified in the `translate` method. Stroking text however, seems to paint the text at exactly the spot I expect it. (This behaviour was observed on Linux and Windows 64-Bit)

Since I am new to JavaFX and Canvas I'm not sure if this is a bug in the JavaFX runtime or if I just use the library the wrong way. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApplication extends Application
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
  {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500,500);
    paint(canvas.getGraphicsContext2D(), canvas.getWidth());

    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    root.add(canvas, 0, 0);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

  private void paint(GraphicsContext graphics, double width)
  {
    //Paint ruler lines on top
    for ( int xCoord = 0; xCoord < width; xCoord+=10 ) {
      graphics.setStroke(Color.RED);
      graphics.beginPath();
      graphics.moveTo(xCoord, 0);
      graphics.lineTo(xCoord, 10);
      graphics.stroke();
    }

    //Paint rectangles and text
    for ( int xCoord = 0; xCoord < width; xCoord+=10 ) {
      graphics.translate(10, 10);

      graphics.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
      graphics.beginPath();
      graphics.rect(0, 0, 300, 300);
      graphics.stroke();

      graphics.strokeText(String.valueOf(xCoord), 0, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

The above application should show a window with a canvas. Inside the canvas there should be 50 rectangles, each rectangle shall be displaced by 10 pixels in x and y direction relative to the previous rectangle. On top of the rectangles, the absolute displacement value should be displayed as string. At the top of the canvas, I painted a 'ruler' to check how wide 10 pixels are.
When I run this example on my computer, the first rectangle starts at 30,30 and the second at 60,60 etc. But the numbers are displayed at the correct position. Please see the picture below (sorry, can't use inline pictures because stackoverflow doesn't allow new users to do so):

[Picture of the application output on my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDlb3.png)

Does anybody have the same problem? Or what do I do wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*NOTE:* It gets even stranger if you comment out the `graphics.beginPath()` in the rectangle paint loop...

**UPDATE:** As pointed out in the comments, I've tried to call `graphics.closePath()` before I'm stroking the path. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to change anything. Also note that using the method `graphics.strokeRect()` instead of the `beginPath,rect[,closePath],stroke` combo, the output is correct (AKA as expected)

**UPDATE2:** Since the GraphicsContext API seems to be based on the HTML5 Canvas API, I've converted the code above to HTML5/Canvas to see what happens. Running it in my Firefox browser, the result of the converted code behaves as expected (does *not* show the strange behaviour like in JavaFX).

I've also tried to use the `strokePolyline` and `strokePolygon` methods in the GraphicsContext API. Using the code below, the path seems to be moved/translated 'only' twice as much as expected.

```
double xCoords[] = { 0, 300, 300,   0,0 };
double yCoords[] = { 0,   0, 300, 300,0 };

graphics.strokePolyline(xCoords, yCoords, xCoords.length);
```

I am really starting to get the feeling that this is indeed a bug in the JavaFX runtime.

**UPDATE3:** I have submitted a bug report to the JavaFX JIRA system: [RT-26119](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-26119). I will update this question with an answer as soon as I get feedback from the JavaFX team.

**UPDATE4:** This problem seems to be solved in the jdk 1.8.0 early access builds (tested with b71)

Regards

Comment: I haven't coded in JavaFX since v.1, but from a quick look at the current docs, your usage of beginPath() before rect() doesn't make sense (IMHO) and at least should be followed by a closePath().

Comment: @PhiLho: Thanks for your input. The javadoc for the `GraphicsContext` class is a bit scarce, so I couldn't really figure out when to call `beginPath/closePath`. Adding the `closePath()` call before the `stroke()` call doesn't change anything unfortunately. It must have something to do with the way I am trying to specify the path though. If I use `strokeRect` instead of the `beginPath,rect,stroke` combo, the output is correct.

Comment: Yes, I found the JavaDoc quite succinct too... I based my answer on my experience with various graphics systems, from Java2D to Processing, and to HTML5 Canvas, as you found out (among others). All these use a similar approach to drawing. What I meant is that rect() isn't really a path (again, generic remark), beginPath in general is more to do a series of line drawings and to close the path for fill purpose. That's why I criticized your usage of beginPath to draw a simple open line or to draw an already closed rectangle.

Comment: @PhiLho: The JavaDoc of the `rect` method says: _Adds path elements to the current path to make a rectangle_. Therefore I thought it makes sense to call `beginPath` first to start a path. Also I've had a look at the [w3c-school website](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp). In the _circle_ example they also call `beginPath` before `arc`, so I figured that would be needed before I call `rect` too.